# Query related class for searching name with spaces

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want a query related class for searching name with spaces in the given queryset.

```
orginal_results_search = FlatCrawlAnalysisResult.objects.using(org_db.db_name).filter(analysis_id=crawlanalysis.id,domain_id=userdomain.domain.id).order_by('id').filter(Q(url__icontains=name))
```

In above i searched `name` in the given query set and filtered them using

```
filter(Q(url__icontains=name))
```

If `name='site_map'` it will return all query which matches with that `name`.

Now what I want is to, if I given `name='site_map'` i.e. (underscored b/w word), i want the query set matches with that name and also if i given name as`'site map'` and `'sitemap'`, it has to return the same matches.

Here the `name` field is dynamic one and not static.

Is there any function like `icontains` to search the name with space also.

Comment: Can you not just slugify the routes?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. Can you make the expected results a little more clearer

Comment: If I given name='site_map' it will return one query set, if i typed 'sitemap' or 'site map', it has to return same query set, for that what i have to do?

Comment: As @JonClements suggested, you could slugify, but that will only work for `site map` not for `sitemap`

Comment: you need full text search